# Python; Pandas; Drop a row that has invalid IP address

Tags: python, pandas, validation, ip-address

I'm currently using netaddr to validate IP addresses from a string of IPs. The string might have some empty(nan) values in it due to which I'm getting the following error.

```
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\netaddr\ip\__init__.py", line 305, in __init__ 
raise AddrFormatError('failed to detect a valid IP ' \
netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: failed to detect a valid IP address from nan
```

The script stops right after it detects its first invalid IP address. It doesn't go through all the records.
I want the script to either store the faulty rows/records in a separate csv file and continue to validate the rest of the data. Or the script can drop the rows with faulty IP address and continue with remaining rows.

below is my implementation to validate IP addresses from a column 'ip'

```
def ipvalidate(df):
    ip = df
    for block in ip_network:
            if IPAddress(ip) in IPNetwork(block):
                return 'int'
            else:
                return 'ext'
```

The df above may not be string(I'm very new to python). Below is the code where the ipvalidate function is being called. Below in (row.ip), the ip is a column in my table

```
    df['detect_ip'] = df.apply(lambda row: ipvalidate(row.ip), axis=1)
```

I have tried to 'dropna' but it keeps complaining about "'dropna' not applicable to string" or something like that.

Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: please share a sample of your data so it can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

I first want to make a comment about your *ipvalidate* function. It says the input of this function is a DataFrame (*def ipvalidate(df):*), but you are passing simply a value to this function (*ipvalidate(row.ip)*, by which you are accessing the value in the "ip" column of the row). I think it still works like it should, but it is confusing for readers. I'd suggest to simplify the top of your function to:

```
def ipvalidate(ip):
   for block in ip_network:
      ...
```

Regarding your problem, I don't think you need your function at all. The following one-liner should work as well:

```
df["detect_ip"] = df["ip"].apply(lambda ip: "int" if IPAddress(ip) in IPNetwork(block) else "ext")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented your code and found this error
```
 in f
    return func(x, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Do you know what can I change?.

Comment: Yes I updated the code in my answer. Basically, you only need to add the "axis" keyword argument in the "apply" function if you apply it on a whole DataFrame (as it needs to know if it should look at columns or at rows). But since in my code we're applying it to a certain column (df["ip"]), it already knows where to look and doesn't need the "axis" keyword argument. So just removing the "axis" keyword argument should make it work.